# Preserving all rows with top n items based on value count in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python and Pandas and have some trouble in working with `DataFrame`s.

I have the following data set in a Pandas `DataFrame`.

```
InvoiceId       StockCode      Price
XXX             ProductA       199,00
XXX             ProductB       78,00
XXX             ProductC       100,00
YYY             ProductB       78,00
YYY             ProductA       199,00
ZZZ             ProductA       199,00
ZZZ             ProductB       78,00

...             ...            ...

ZZZ             ProductY       19,00
```

I want to count how often each product was purchased and keep the top n products in my `DataFrame`. How can I do that?

For example, for the top n=2 products, the result would be as follows.

```
InvoiceId       StockCode      Price
XXX             ProductA       199,00
XXX             ProductB       78,00
YYY             ProductB       78,00
YYY             ProductA       199,00
ZZZ             ProductA       199,00
ZZZ             ProductB       78,00
```

I.e., the rows with ProductC and ProductZ were removed.

In the end, I want to present the data with the top n products as follows.

```
         ProductA    ProductB
XXX          1           1
YYY          1           1
ZZZ          1           1
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
#convert column to numeric
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)

#get top2 values from index
print (df['Price'].value_counts().iloc[:2])
78.0     3
199.0    3
Name: Price, dtype: int64

#filter rows with top2 values (78, 199)
df = df[df['Price'].isin(df['Price'].value_counts().iloc[:2].index)]
print (df)
  InvoiceId StockCode  Price
0       XXX  ProductA  199.0
1       XXX  ProductB   78.0
3       YYY  ProductB   78.0
4       YYY  ProductA  199.0
5       ZZZ  ProductA  199.0
6       ZZZ  ProductB   78.0

#count top2
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['InvoiceId'],
                  df['StockCode'])
print (df1)
StockCode  ProductA  ProductB
InvoiceId                    
XXX               1         1
YYY               1         1
ZZZ               1         1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why did you sort by 'Price'?

Comment: I also added more details to my question.

Comment: Now it is correct. Sorry. I already figured out the crosstab function but I don't know how to filter rows from the dataframe.